# How to get filename structure in a folder in Matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, filenames, matlab-guide

I am designing a GUI in Matlab,

I have a folder called `sth`. It contains many files having same structure like,

```
filename_1_something.mat
filename_2_something.mat
```

In order to loop over filenames by selecting via index, I need to find a resulting string like this;

```
filename_%d_something.mat
```

So I don't need to read all the files in the dir. Two of the filenames are enough to compare strings and find the different char array item and change by `%d`.

Or anything different than this also appreciated.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Haha, I am asking that, how can I find the desired filename pattern out of existing at most 100 filenames inside of a folder.

Comment: use this regex :- `filename_\d+_something.mat` for comparing file name

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, user will select the folder and I don't have any info about the filenames inside of the folder. Filename strcuture can be anything but index number somewhere in it.

Comment: I saw your regex. But I can't use regex I guess. I don't have the pattern. I need to find the pattern

Comment: aha, so the structure can be anything? its not known beforehand?

Comment: Yeap. That is the problem. Actually, dir function in Matlab gets the filenames as array of struct. But the order of files are not correct. it follows like fn_100_.mat, fn_10_.mat, fn_1_.mat, fn_2._mat etc.

Comment: i don't follow you..is the structure of names like `filename_[digits]_something.mat`

Comment: I am just giving examples :). strings before and after of digits can be anything :). Your patern is ok for me.

Comment: there are two underscores before and after digits?

Comment: in that case you can use this regex :- `\w*_\d+_\w*\.mat`

Comment: so what if, string starts with the digit and after an underscore and something like [digits]_something.mat.

And how should I change it into the patern that I want like

filename_%d_something.mat

Comment: that's why I asked will there be two underscores?

Comment: Not sure, It is up to the client.

Comment: is there anything in pattern that is fixed?

Comment: @freezer your comments contradicts, please test the regex provided by rock321987 and find cases where it does not work for you - the regex does "change it into the patern that I want like filename_%d_something.mat"

Comment: Nope. I thought that, if I can compare two filenames and find which chars are different I can and substring to that location. But this time, length of index digit matters. And it takes time to read 100 files. Lets say I have filename_1_something.m and  filename_2_something.m matlab can give me that 10th char is different then I replace 2 with %d and everything is OK. But I need to choos two filenames as same length. if I select filename_1_something.m and filename_10_something.m it wont work. Or maybe I need to compare the lenggth of the files also.

Comment: reading the filenames take literally 0.0001 second, so you should be able to have all of the filenames under the dir - if you compare the length of the filenames, what if you have a file that just happens to be foreign and breaks? Once you load in all the filenames, you can do whatever `strcmp` you like.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I used regexp given by rock321987, it just gave me the filename, So how should I find the position of the digits and change into %d. Sorry for the lack of knowledge about regexp btw.

Comment: regexprep(files(1).name,'(\w*)_(\d+)_(\w*)\.mat','$1_%d_$3')  this worked for the case with two underscores before and after the digits. How can it be improved to cover where it begins or ends with the digits?

Comment: @freezer add an other regex or if you are only looking for underscores, just use userscore as your regex

Comment: if you can add all your requirements, then it can be solved

Comment: @GameOfThrows I have check the directory reading time as; 
for p = 1:length(paths.mesDir)
       mes = paths.mesDir{p};
       tic;
       files = dir([mes '\*.mat']);
       toc;
end

end yields ~11 secs.

Comment: the directory reading time should be just dir('*.mat') which is the time needed to create the stuct with all your file names in it, the for loops do not count.

Comment: there are multiple folders. it just runs for one folder. And the 11sec is just for 1 dir() fcn.

Comment: dir does subfolders, so no need to loop it for each folder.

Comment: Folders not recursive. It loops over different folders to find file patters for each folders.

Comment: I see...well, I don't see any other methods that will go much faster - you might have to bear with the 11 seconds..

Comment: Thanks. I am very appreciated with your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the regex provided by @rock321987 -

```
 names = dir('*.mat');
 num = length(names);
 expression = '\w*_\d+_\w*\.mat';
 for n = 1:num
    str = names(n).name;
    nameList{n} = regexp(str,expression,'match')
 end
```

works on:

```
test_1_something.mat
test_10_something.mat
```

changing the regex to just `\w*_\w*\.mat`

works for

```
test_1.mat
1_test.mat
test_1_something.mat
test_10_something.mat
```

but also works for anything with an string joined by underscore .mat

Comment: Thanks, but I needed something to be able to replace the digits with %d two char string. I tried a few expressions and came up with the working one. I hope there will be no error. regexprep('test_100_something.mat','(\w*_|^)(\d+)(_\w*\.mat)','$1%d$3');